How to get a static property from a generic argument in C#?
My goal is to have an abstract class representing one of many DAO objects, any of which can be put into an internal cache indexed by a cache key.  The actual processing is done in a separate processor class which takes in the specific DAO class as a generic argument.  I am trying to figure out how to use the generic argument to determine the correct cache key
what I'm attempting is basically this
abstract class Dao {
  // some kind of static string called "CacheKeyStem". The below doesn't work because you can't have abstract static properties
  abstract static string CacheKeyStem { get; }

  int Id { get; set; }

  string CacheKey => $"{CacheKeyStem}-{Id}";
}

PersonDao : Dao {
  // override CacheKeyStem. Again, this doesn't work
  public static override string CacheKeyStem => "Person";
}

CarDao : Dao {
  // override CacheKeyStem. Again, this doesn't work
  public static override string CacheKeyStem => "Car";
}

So now we have 2 DAOs, one for persons and one for cars.  In my processor class, I have
abstract class BaseProcessor<T> where T : Dao {
  public void AddToCache(T obj){
    _myCache.Add(obj.CacheKey, obj);
  }

  public T RetrieveFromCache(int id){
    // the below obviously doesnt work either.
    return _myCache.Get<T>($"{T.CacheKeyStem}-{id}"); 
  }
}

I'm sure there's a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here, but I'm not sure what it is.  Within RetrieveFromCache, we know the type of the object we want, but we don't have an instance.  We know that the type extends Dao.  I need a way to get the CacheKeyStem based on the type of the generic argument.

You can do it with static interface methods available from C#11 and .NET 7:
For your case, something like this:
interface IHaveCacheKeyStem {
    abstract static string CacheKeyStem { get; }
}

abstract class Dao {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CacheKey => $"{GetCacheKeyStem()}-{Id}";
    protected abstract string GetCacheKeyStem();
}

class PersonDao : Dao, IHaveCacheKeyStem {
    public static string CacheKeyStem => "Person";
    protected override string GetCacheKeyStem() => CacheKeyStem;
}

class CarDao : Dao, IHaveCacheKeyStem {
    public static string CacheKeyStem => "Car";
    protected override string GetCacheKeyStem() => CacheKeyStem;
}

abstract class BaseProcessor<T> where T : Dao, IHaveCacheKeyStem {
    // example cache
    Dictionary<string, T> _myCache = new();
    public void AddToCache(T obj) {
        _myCache.Add(obj.CacheKey, obj);
    }

    public T RetrieveFromCache(int id) {
        // T.CacheKeyStem would work
        // dictionary doesn't have Get<T> method though
        // so won't compile
        return _myCache.Get<T>($"{T.CacheKeyStem}-{id}");
    }
}

example use:
var personDao = new PersonDao() { Id = 42 };
Console.WriteLine(personDao.CacheKey); // Person-42
var carDao = new CarDao() { Id = 42 };
Console.WriteLine(carDao.CacheKey); // Car-42


This might be better if it used more of the example code the OP presented in the question OR explain why it might NOT be useable

@MarkSchultheiss thanks, edited with a possible implementation for OP's exact case.

You can use reflection:
var type = typeof(T);
var prop = type.GetProperty("CacheKeyStem", BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Static|BibdingFlags.GetProperty);
if (prop != null)
{
    var key = prop.GetValue(null);
    return _myCache.Get<T>($"{key}-{id}");
    /* rest goes here */
}

With this you get the value, which you can use.

Thanks, @Dai! I wrote this on the phone, didn't notice! Fixed now!


When converting the code to IL, we observe that abstract methods are called using the callvirt instruction. This signifies that they are virtual by nature and rely on a runtime mechanism called the vtable (virtual table).
IL Abstract.
A vtable is a per-class table that holds references to the implementations of virtual and abstract methods. This table allows derived classes to override the base class's abstract or virtual methods. At compile time, the compiler ensures that the derived class refers to the base class’s vtable and updates the entries to point to the correct implementations from the derived class.
IL override

This mechanism inherently relies on object instances to resolve the method calls at runtime, which is why abstract methods are tied to instance-based polymorphism.

However, static methods work entirely differently in C#. They are not associated with instances of a class but rather with the class itself. Static methods are resolved at compile time based on the type, and they do not participate in the vtable mechanism. Because static methods are not tied to an instance, there is no runtime resolution, and they cannot be overridden or abstracted like instance methods.IL Static

Due to this fundamental difference, it is not possible to define static abstract methods in a class. The runtime has no mechanism to support such behavior, as it would require combining type-level resolution (for static methods) with instance-level polymorphism (for abstract methods), which is not supported in C#.
The implementation has already been written above
